# Moving and redesigning a website

Tags: seo, cms, pagerank

I am currently in the process of redesigning a successful business website.  First I will be moving the site to a new web host.  Once it is up and running I will begin porting the site into Joomla.

Are their any considerations that I need to take into account to keep our rankings where they are?  My goal is to also improve our rank as quickly as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are changing domain and/or the pages URLs of your websites, yes there  are some considerations to make about SEO.

You should redirect 301 all the old URLs of pages from the old website to the new website's URLs.

Read this similar question and answer: [Moving from a static site to a CMS with new URLs and meta-data for pages](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/6546/moving-from-a-static-site-to-a-cms-with-new-urls-and-meta-data-for-pages)